# Display hidden div and hide button on click

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript function to open a hidden div on click, but I want also to remove / hide the button on click. I know it's possible, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
<span id="first_related">
    content 1
</span>

<span id="second_related" style="display:none;">
    content 2 hidden / display on click
</span>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="btn">
<input id="current_page_viewed_videos" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden" id="related_videos_delta"><a onclick="showDiv()">Show More</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv() {
       document.getElementById('second_related').style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById('open').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the markup for the button?

Comment: You could set the id of the anchor element: `<a id="open" onclick="showDiv()">`. It would be hidden on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript is OK, all that you need is just to add `<button id="open" onclick="showDiv()">click</button>`:

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('second_related').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('open').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<span id="first_related">
content 1
</span>

<span id="second_related" style="display:none;">
content 2 hidden / display on click
</span>

<button id="open" onclick="showDiv()">click</button>
```

**For updated question:**

```js
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('second_related').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('open').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<span id="first_related">
    content 1
</span>

<span id="second_related" style="display:none;">
    content 2 hidden / display on click
</span>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="btn">
<input id="current_page_viewed_videos" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden" id="related_videos_delta"><a id="open" onclick="showDiv()">Show More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the button so with my code I can open the hidden div but the button remains visible.

Comment: @Gazi does your button has an `id="open"`? Because in your code you're getting button by id.

Comment: Yes sorry I just changed it to `document.getElementById('second_related').style.display = "block";document.getElementById('related_videos_delta').style.display = "none";` but the button is still there after click.

Comment: Great! yes I moved ID to `<a id="related_videos_delta">` and worked fine thankyou verymuch!

Answer (score 0):

using jquery this could be simple. Give you button an id (eg id='mybutton'), 
then in your code that shows the div add: 
$('#mybutton').hide()